# Google Apps Script - How to loop through dataset and create tabs in Google Sheets File with Data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a dataset that I would like to slice and dice into several sub datasets that I want to copy over as new tabs in the same Google Sheets file. The subsets will be determined based on the unique values in a column (in this ex: Employees). One major problem I'm having is that the column I want to filter by (Employees) is a column with strings containing a name and some numbers that are concatenated together. Below is an example of how the field looks:

| Employee |
| --- |
| Jessica124 |
| Billy01157 |
| Josh124753 |
| Billy13355 |
| Jessica235 |
| Jax3589689 |

How can I filter the dataset by just the Employee (text part) in the above field and then paste the subset of data pertaining to the employee in another tab in the same Google Sheets file? The full dataset contains about 10 - 20 columns.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Using String.match() with regex you can get the names minus the numbers.  Then you can Array.filter() to get all the items matching a name.  I'm assuming you would have a sheet for each name, but I leave it to you to put the results to each sheet.

Lets say the sheet looks like this.

[image]

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  values.shift(); // remove headers
  // get only column A
  let employees = values.map( row => row[0]);
  // now get unique values
  employees = [...new Set(employees.map( employee => employee.match(/[a-z]+/i)[0]))];
  // now lets get the tasks for each employee
  employees.forEach( employee => {
    console.log("Employee: "+employee);
    let tasks = values.filter( row => row[0].includes(employee));
    console.log(tasks);
  });
}
```

**Execution log**

```
9:32:10 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:32:11 AM  Info    Employee: Jessica
9:32:11 AM  Info    [ [ 'Jessica124', 1 ], [ 'Jessica235', 5 ], [ 'Jessica678', 9 ] ]
9:32:11 AM  Info    Employee: Billy
9:32:11 AM  Info    [ [ 'Billy01157', 2 ], [ 'Billy13355', 4 ], [ 'Billy99999', 8 ] ]
9:32:11 AM  Info    Employee: Josh
9:32:11 AM  Info    [ [ 'Josh124753', 3 ], [ 'Josh2222222', 7 ] ]
9:32:11 AM  Info    Employee: Jax
9:32:11 AM  Info    [ [ 'Jax3589689', 6 ], [ 'Jax0000000', 10 ] ]
9:32:12 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Array.shift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp)
- [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [Set Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [Array.filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)