# How Do I Split Table Data in One Tab Into Multiple Separate Tabs Based on "Name" Column Value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, split, tabs

Let's say I have the following sample Google Sheets table called "table_raw":

| Name | Date | Value | Wtd | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | 11/6/2023 | 3 | 0.75 | 44 |
| Jim | 11/6/2023 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| Dan | 11/6/2023 | 5 | 1.3 | 37 |
| Dan | 11/13/2023 | 6 | 1 | 28 |
| Dan | 11/13/2023 | 8 | 0.63 | 1 |
| Dan | 11/13/2023 | 0 | 1.1 | 13 |
| Chloe | 12/14/2023 | 2 | 0.7 | 40 |
| Chloe | 12/14/2023 | 4 | 1.9 | 33 |
| Chloe | 12/14/2023 | 1 | 2.2 | 2 |

I want to split this data into separate tabs (inside the same Google Sheet workbook) based on the "Name" column.  Specifically I have 3 tabs in my Google Sheet already named Jim, Dan, and Chloe.  I want to:

- delete all data in each of those 3 existing tabs
- populate each tab with the corresponding name's "table_raw" data

As an example, the Jim tab would now look like this:

```
| Name  | Date       | Value | Wtd  | Count |
|-------|------------|-------|------|------:|
| Jim   |  11/6/2023 |     3 | 0.75 |    44 |
| Jim   |  11/6/2023 |     2 |    1 |     2 |
```

And the Chloe Google Sheet tab would look like this:

```
| Name  | Date       | Value | Wtd  | Count |
| Chloe | 12/14/2023 |     2 |  0.7 |    40 |
| Chloe | 12/14/2023 |     4 |  1.9 |    33 |
| Chloe | 12/14/2023 |     1 |  2.2 |     2 |
```

From my understanding, this is something I may be able to do with AppsScript and JS?  After searching around online, I honestly have no idea how to do this.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do [Google Apps Script - How to loop through dataset and create tabs in Google Sheets File with Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73069827/15384825) and

[Create a new sheet in a Google Sheets with Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57811296) answer your question?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want a simple QUERY() function in A1 of each tab?

Answer (score 3):

### Alternate Solution

You may also try this method.

**Script:**

```
function mainFunction() {
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("table_raw");
  let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  values.shift(); // remove headers
  // get only column A
  let employees = values.map(row => row[0]);
  // now get unique values
  employees = [...new Set(employees.map(employee => employee.match(/[a-z]+/i)[0]))];

  // now lets get the data for each employee
  var employeeData = employees.map(employee => {
    let data = values.filter(row => row[0].includes(employee));
    return [employee, data];
  });

  //Create sheet tab for each employees
  employeeData.forEach(employee => createSheetTabs(spread, employee))
}

function createSheetTabs(spread, employee) {
  //Check if there's already an existing sheet name.
  if (spread.getSheets().filter(sheet => sheet.getName() == employee[0]).length == 0) {
    //create the sheet tab for the employee
    spread.insertSheet(employee[0]);
    //add the employee data
    employee[1].unshift(['Name','Date','Value','Wtd','Count'])
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(employee[0]).getRange(1,1,employee[1].length,employee[1][0].length).setValues(employee[1]);
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(employee[0]).getRange(1,1,employee[1].length,employee[1][0].length).setValues(employee[1]);
  }
}
```

This script will auto update existing employee tabs Or create sheet tabs for unique users (just in case certain employee/s from main tab do not have existing tabs yet), filters the data for each users and then push each data to the created sheet tabs for each users.

**Sample result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Selecting sheets by name and loading respective rows in each sheet

```
function sortof() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [hs, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  vs.reduce((a, r, i) => {
    if (i == 0) a["sA"].forEach(n => a[n] = new Array)
    a[r[0]].push(r);
    return a;
  }, { sA: ["Jim", "Dan", "Chloe"], "loadData": function () {
      this.sA.forEach(name => {
        let sh = ss.getSheetByName(name);
        sh.clearContents();
        this[name].unshift(hs);
        sh.getRange(1, 1, this[name].length, this[name][0].length).setValues(this[name]);
      })
    }
  }).loadData()
}
```

Sheet0:

| Name | Date | Value | Wtd | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | 11/6/2023 | 3 | 0.75 | 44 |
| Jim | 11/6/2023 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| Dan | 11/6/2023 | 5 | 1.3 | 37 |
| Dan | 11/13/2023 | 6 | 1 | 28 |
| Dan | 11/13/2023 | 8 | 0.63 | 1 |
| Dan | 11/13/2023 | 0 | 1.1 | 13 |
| Chloe | 12/14/2023 | 2 | 0.7 | 40 |
| Chloe | 12/14/2023 | 4 | 1.9 | 33 |
| Chloe | 12/14/2023 | 1 | 2.2 | 2 |

Jim:

| Name | Date | Value | Wtd | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | 11/06/2023 | 3 | 0.75 | 44 |
| Jim | 11/06/2023 | 2 | 1 | 2 |

Dan:

| Name | Date | Value | Wtd | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dan | 11/6/2023 | 5 | 1.3 | 37 |
| Dan | 11/13/2023 | 6 | 1 | 28 |
| Dan | 11/13/2023 | 8 | 0.63 | 1 |
| Dan | 11/13/2023 | 0 | 1.1 | 13 |

Chloe:

| Name | Date | Value | Wtd | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chloe | 12/14/2023 | 2 | 0.7 | 40 |
| Chloe | 12/14/2023 | 4 | 1.9 | 33 |
| Chloe | 12/14/2023 | 1 | 2.2 | 2 |

- [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: Thanks, Cooper.  When I ran the code on my Google Sheet I got two errors: 

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Error 1: vs.reduce.sA @ Code.gs:7.

Error 2: sortof @ Code.gs:5

Comment: I cannot confirm that problem.  Supposedly I have the same table of data that you do.  If that is not true then provide me with the correct information

Comment: You may need to expand the sA Array in the reduce function if you require more than three names